# Find first zero in row of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame, we'll call `a`, that looks like:

[image]

I have another DataFrame of the same form, but contains different figures. I am trying to fill the last non-zero value with the value in the same location of the other DataFrame. I'm having trouble even conceptualizing how to do this without looping through each row, then each column for that row and doing value comparisons. Is there another, better, way to do this?

Comment: this would be a much easier question to answer if you provided a runnable example that 1) generated a smaller amount of representative code and 2) demonstrated what you've tried already.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback @PaulH . I'll add to this tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly:

It is late, but I am going to take stab anyway.

```
(dfin.ne(0).T[::-1].cumsum().eq(1)[::-1].T*df_2).replace(0,pd.np.nan).combine_first(dfin)
```

How it works:

- Find all non-zero values in dataframe
- Transpose so I can count the non-zero in reverse order
- Use eq(1) to mask all other values except the first non-zero 
  datafame
- Reverse order and transpose back to original shape and sort
- Substitute NaN for zeroes.
- Mulitply by df_2 to get replacement values
- Lastly, use combine_first to substitute NaNs with dfin values.

Inputs:

```
print(dfin)
        2017-05-31  2017-06-30  2017-07-31  2017-08-31  2017-09-30  \
560101      7910.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0   
364672      7457.0      4656.0      5778.0      1482.0      2906.0   
786073      2201.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0   
437551      3063.0      5975.0      7518.0         0.0         0.0   
343474      3263.0      3559.0      8417.0      1024.0         0.0   
742817      6997.0      2192.0      6550.0      8410.0      7804.0   
197776      2177.0      8532.0      4019.0      3373.0      2529.0   
262179      8696.0      4426.0         0.0         0.0         0.0   
867695      6766.0      4775.0      7633.0      4556.0      8619.0   
266410      3385.0      1746.0      4360.0      1561.0      9184.0   

        2017-10-31  2017-11-30  2017-12-31  2018-01-31  2018-02-28  
560101         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0  
364672      3541.0      3078.0      9971.0         0.0         0.0  
786073         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0  
437551         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0  
343474         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0  
742817      4009.0      7788.0      9376.0         0.0         0.0  
197776      5658.0      7246.0      7403.0      3186.0      2669.0  
262179         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0  
867695      2867.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0  
266410         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0  

print(df_2) #replacement values datafame
        2017-05-31  2017-06-30  2017-07-31  2017-08-31  2017-09-30  \
560101        9999        9999        9999        9999        9999   
364672        9999        9999        9999        9999        9999   
786073        9999        9999        9999        9999        9999   
437551        9999        9999        9999        9999        9999   
343474        9999        9999        9999        9999        9999   
742817        9999        9999        9999        9999        9999   
197776        9999        9999        9999        9999        9999   
262179        9999        9999        9999        9999        9999   
867695        9999        9999        9999        9999        9999   
266410        9999        9999        9999        9999        9999   

        2017-10-31  2017-11-30  2017-12-31  2018-01-31  2018-02-28  
560101        9999        9999        9999        9999        9999  
364672        9999        9999        9999        9999        9999  
786073        9999        9999        9999        9999        9999  
437551        9999        9999        9999        9999        9999  
343474        9999        9999        9999        9999        9999  
742817        9999        9999        9999        9999        9999  
197776        9999        9999        9999        9999        9999  
262179        9999        9999        9999        9999        9999  
867695        9999        9999        9999        9999        9999  
266410        9999        9999        9999        9999        9999
```

Replace the *last non-zero value* on **each row** in dfin with the value in the same location from df_2.

```
(dfin.ne(0).T[::-1].cumsum().eq(1)[::-1].T*df_2).replace(0,pd.np.nan).combine_first(dfin)
```

Output:

```
        2017-05-31  2017-06-30  2017-07-31  2017-08-31  2017-09-30  \
560101      9999.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0   
364672      7457.0      4656.0      5778.0      1482.0      2906.0   
786073      9999.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0   
437551      3063.0      5975.0      9999.0         0.0         0.0   
343474      3263.0      3559.0      8417.0      9999.0         0.0   
742817      6997.0      2192.0      6550.0      8410.0      7804.0   
197776      2177.0      8532.0      4019.0      3373.0      2529.0   
262179      8696.0      9999.0         0.0         0.0         0.0   
867695      6766.0      4775.0      7633.0      4556.0      8619.0   
266410      3385.0      1746.0      4360.0      1561.0      9999.0   

        2017-10-31  2017-11-30  2017-12-31  2018-01-31  2018-02-28  
560101         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0  
364672      3541.0      3078.0      9999.0         0.0         0.0  
786073         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0  
437551         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0  
343474         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0  
742817      4009.0      7788.0      9999.0         0.0         0.0  
197776      5658.0      7246.0      7403.0      3186.0      9999.0  
262179         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0  
867695      9999.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0  
266410         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
```

Comment: My question was terrible, and this is exactly what I was looking for. I would upvote 10 times if I could. Let me implement quick and I'll marked answered once I know it works.